# How can i save inputs to my browser's local storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, local-storage

I made a todo list app using jQuery, it works okay but i realized that whenever i refresh my page, the todos disappears, it's completely gone. I've sought online for possible solutions to this problem and i found it could be remedied with windows.localStorage property. But i really can't make it work as intended in mine. I want a situation whereby, whenever i refresh my page, the browser should remember and keep the todos entered.
Below is a sample of my code:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).remove()
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text'").keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which === 13) {
        var toDoText = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></span> " + toDoText + "</li");
        localStorage.setItem("input", toDoText);
    }
});
$(".fa-pen").click(function() {
$("input[type='text'").fadeToggle();
})
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem`

Comment: I've tried localStorage.getItem, but it seems am going about implementing it wrongly

Comment: well then also include the wrong implementation so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use setItem you save in your localstorage item with key 'input' and value of your var.
In order to read you value back you will need to use
`localStorage.getItem("input")` this will fetch you the item you have stored.
btw if you use chrome you can see the storage data in realtime. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/localstorage
now you should write code that will read you item from the storage and show it in case its exists.
try to think how you want to store you data of your todo array, json and so on.
keep in mind that if you choose to store your data in json type you will have to
convert it and then parse it for example:
`localStorage.setItem("input", JSON.toStringify([{"comment" : "my first comment"}, {"comment" : "my second comment"}]));`
and when you want to get the data:
`var myComments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("input"))`